# Office 2013 encountered error during setup on Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, microsoft-office-2013

I have been encountering an error when installing Office 2013 after uninstalling the preview.  Everytime I try to install I get this error in the logs

```
Error: Failed to configure:  {90150000-00C1-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} ErrorCode: 1624(0x658).
```

I know the error code has something to do with an error in applying transforms but other than that don't really know what this is and how to remedy it.

Full logs are [Here](http://pastebin.com/C35xEvDh)

Comment: try this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpropreview/thread/356e6135-2a4e-4b72-b9d5-3f5454932d93/. You can also ask in this office forum. The chances are better to get help there.